# setting Android NDK giving error : Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm running a sample application given in android-ndk, i have done basic settings like setting NDK Path at windows->preferences->android->NDK . Adding native support into project, included directories at c/c++ genereal-> paths and symbols -> includes  but project is still showing error , if i clean the project it will generate error shown below . Any one knows what this errors means and what is the solution for this?

```
**** Clean-only build of configuration Default for project HelloJni ****

    F:\android-ndk-r9-windows-x86\android-ndk-r9\ndk-build.cmd clean 
    Android NDK: Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: ;F:\android-ndk-r9-windows-x86\android-ndk-r9/jni/Android.mk    
    F:/android-ndk-r9-windows-x86/android-ndk-r9/build/core/add-application.mk:176: *** Android NDK: Aborting...    .  Stop.

**** Build Finished ****
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like ndk-build looks for jni/Android.mk under NDK directory and it is clearly wrong. Before running ndk-build, you should change your directory to project directory. For ease of use, add NDK directory to Path in your environment variables first, then change your directory to project directory and run ndk-build then. Like (assuming NDK directory is added to environment variables):

```
cd F:\path\to\project
ndk-build
```